# Number of times $\mu$-operator needs to be used

Tags: logic, recursion, computability, recursive-algorithms

I found the following statement in my old notes: to prove that a function is $\mu$-recursive, we never need to use the $\mu$-operator more than once. Why is this true (if this is even true)? What if the $f$ from below is itself defined using $\mu$-operator? Then if we need to define $g$, we would be using the $\mu$-operator more than once.

> if $f:N^{k+1}\to N$ is $\mu$-recursive, then so is $g:N^k\to N$ defined by $g(x_1,\dots,x_k)=\mu y. (f(x_1,\dots,x_k,y)=0)$.

Comment: For intuition purposes i like to think of it as follows: Let's say you want to simulate a given Turing machine with partial recursive functions. In such construction you don't need $\mu$ in the "step" function that computes how the state of the tape changes from time t, to t+1, you only need $\mu$ after, to iterate the process of applying such step function.

Answer (score 2):

The most natural way to prove this, in my opinion, is via the "syntactic" approach to computability. Specifically, use the following results:

> **Fact 1**: If $\theta(x_1,...,x_n)$ is $\Delta^0_0$ (that is, only uses bounded quantifiers), then the function $$t_\theta(x_1,...,x_n)=\begin{cases}
> 1&\mbox{ if }\theta(x_1,...,x_n),\\
> 0&\mbox{ otherwise}\\
> \end{cases}$$ is primitive recursive.

(Interestingly the converse of this **fails** since we can diagonalize out of the $\Delta^0_0$ functions in a primitive recursive way.)

> **Fact 2**: A partial function $f:\subseteq\mathbb{N}^k\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ is $\mu$-recursive iff there is a formula $\psi(x_1,...,x_k, y, z)$ in the language of arithmetic such that:
>
> - $\psi$ is $\Delta^0_0$, that is, it uses only bounded quantifiers.
> - We have $f(a_1,...,a_k)\downarrow=b$ iff $\exists y\psi(a_1,...,a_k,y,b)$ holds.

Now suppose $f$ is $k$-ary and $\mu$-recursive. Let $\psi$ be as guaranteed by Fact $2$. Let $\pi_0,\pi_1$ be the left and right projections corresponding to the Cantor pairing function, so that $a=\langle \pi_0(a),\pi_1(a)\rangle$ for each $a$, and consider the map $$g(x_1,...,x_k)=\mu a. (t_\psi(x_1,...,x_k, \pi_0(a),\pi_1(a))=0)$$ (which per Fact $1$ only uses one instance of $\mu$ since $t_\psi$ is primitive recursive). The function $f$ is then $\pi_1(g(x_1,...,x_k))$.

---

Of course, in order to do this you have to prove Facts $1$ and $2$ in the first place, and this is nontrivial. However, it's absolutely worth doing: the syntactic approach to computability cannot be over-valued. In particular, the *converse* of Fact $2$ is used all the time in logic.